# Best language tooling

Tags: java

I was listening to a podcast recently (may have been SO - can't remember) when the interviewee said that one of the reasons Java was so successful and popular was the tooling.

Having use of great FOSS editors such as Eclipse, NetBeans. Metrics tools such as Cobertura, Find Bugs, Build tools such as Maven and ANT.. I'd have to agree

I've done a fair bit of .NET and the tools are OKish. The problem seems to be that there isn't the depth in tooling that there is in Java. The FOSS stuff seems pretty limited.

My question: Are there any modern languages with a better community and tooling for getting the job done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget Perl's [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) with a wealth of first-class code like e.g. [profilers](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-2.09/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm), [ide's](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Padre-0.34/lib/Padre.pm) and [modern Object Oriented Systems](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.77/lib/Moose.pm).

C.

Answer (score 2):

sure, there's emacs and vi!

seriously, great as some Java tools are, many of their features are meaningless for other languages/environments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for languages other than Java and C# with good tool and library support, I think the next most supported language is Ruby.  However, I believe the tool, library, and community support for Ruby is much less than Java or C#.

Answer (score 1):

maybe PHP or even python

Comment: Could you name some PHP tools that compare to Eclipse, NetBeans, Cobertura, Find Bugs, Maven and Ant, which the PO named?

Comment: I disagree with dfa regarding PHP having good tooling but I certainly do make use of Netbeans and Ant for the PHP project I have the misfortune to work on.   Great tools, but aren't as great as they are when working with Java.